# How to exclude results in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this sql query. Wherein I do not want to select the records which has Type that is not equal to 1. What's the problem with this query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM admin_table
WHERE Type !=  '1'
AND Uneym LIKE  '%'
OR Email LIKE  '%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: what you get if you run this query, it seems good

Comment: You are returning everything as the query is technically (Type != '1' AND Uneym is anything) OR (Email is anything). Seeing as Email will always be something the `WHERE` will always return everything. Do as kappa says below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wrap your where condition in parenthesis:

```
where `type` <> 1 and (`uneym` like '%%' or `email` like '%%')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM admin_table
WHERE Type <>  '1'
AND Uneym LIKE  '%'
OR Email LIKE  '%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: is type a reserved word for mysql?It seems to be capitalizing the word type. Once I execute it.

Comment: `!=` should also work. It's because of the `OR` statement that it doesn't work.

Comment: i never knew that != worked....never tried it, always have used <>...learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM admin_table
WHERE NOT Type =  '1'
AND (Uneym LIKE  '%' OR Email LIKE  '%')
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

one remark you do not need the condition

```
AND Uneym LIKE  '%'
OR Email LIKE  '%'
```

because it say bring me all

```
 Type !=  1
```

or

```
 Type <>  1
```

its not matter , [both syntax work](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)